# Creating symbolic link in the same directory

Tags: linux, directory, symlink

Having some trouble with creating links. I want to create the following:

```
ls -la /usr/pkgs/python3/
total 44
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root 4096 Sep  3  2020 .
drwxrwxr-x 259 root root 20480 Feb 16 06:49 ..
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root 4096 Jan  9  2018 3.6.3
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    5 Nov  8  2018 3.6.3a -> 3.6.3
```

I ran:

```
ln -s /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3 /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a
```

But it creates:

```
ls -la /usr/pkgs/python3/
total 0
drwxrwxr-x 3 root root 20 Mar 27 23:47 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 root root 21 Mar 27 23:47 ..
drwxrwxr-x 4 root root 41 Mar 27 23:47 3.6.3a

ls -la /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a/
total 0
drwxrwxr-x 4 root root 41 Mar 27 23:47 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 root root 20 Mar 27 23:47 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Mar 27 23:48 3.6.3 -> /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3
```

Note that I want to use realpath in the link and not relative like in the example above `3.6.3a -> 3.6.3`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

That happens because there already is a directory named `3.6.3a` in `/usr/pkgs/python3/`.

The `ln` command has more than one form. Quoting the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/ln.html) (emphasis mine):

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> ln [-fs] [-L|-P] source_file target_file
> ```
>
> ```
> ln [-fs] [-L|-P] source_file... target_dir
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> In the first synopsis form, the `ln` utility shall create a new directory entry (link) at the destination path specified by the *target_file operand*. If the `-s` option is specified, a symbolic link shall be created for the file specified by the *source_file* operand. This first synopsis form **shall be assumed when the final operand does not name an existing directory**; ...
>
> In the second synopsis form, the `ln` utility shall create a new directory entry (link), or if the `-s` option is specified a symbolic link, for each file specified by a *source_file* operand, at a destination path in the **existing** directory named by *target_dir*.

If you had a file (in a broad sense: not necessarily a regular file) named `3.6.3` in `/usr/pkgs/python3/` (and no files named `3.6.3a`) the command you ran would have given the expected result.

Note that (assuming `3.6.3` exists and `3.6.3a` does not)

```bsh
ln -s /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3 /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a
```

creates a link to an absolute path, while

```bsh
ln -s 3.6.3 /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a
```

creates a relative link named `3.6.3a` to a file named `3.6.3` which is supposed to be in the same directory as the link itself. (And may of course use `ln -s ../path/to/3.6.3 /usr/pkgs/python3/3.6.3a` to make a relative link to a file located in a different directory).
The GNU implementation of `ln` has a `-r` option that allows you to create a relative link out of an absolute path:

```bsh
$ cd /tmp/
$ mkdir dir dir/subdir
$ touch file
$ ln -sr /tmp/file dir/subdir/link_to_file
$ ls -gG /tmp/dir/subdir/link_to_file 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 10 Mar 28 01:31 /tmp/dir/subdir/link_to_file -> ../../file
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easiest to just jump into that directory and create the link:

```
cd /usr/pkgs/python3/
ln -sf  3.6.3  3.6.3a
cd -
```

Or with a subshell:

```
( cd /usr/pkgs/python3/ ; ln -sf  3.6.3  3.6.3a )
```